# What is .net dynamic data and why would I use it?

Tags: .net, dynamic-data

What is .net dynamic data and why would I use it?

Answer (score 6):

From [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/14/new-asp-net-dynamic-data-support.aspx) a great article on how to use Dynamic Data.

> One of the cool new features is something we call "ASP.NET Dynamic Data Support". In a nutshell this enables you to
>   really quickly build data driven
>   web-sites that work against a LINQ to
>   SQL (and in the future LINQ to
>   Entities) object model - and
>   optionally allows you to-do this
>   without having to build any pages
>   manually.

See this [screencast](http://blogs.msdn.com/davidebb/archive/2007/12/12/dynamic-data-screencast-is-now-available.aspx). It is very enlightening.

From more official [ASP.NET Dynamic Data site](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata/):

> ASP.NET Dynamic Data provides a
>   framework that enables you to quickly
>   build a functional data-driven
>   application, based on a LINQ to SQL or
>   Entity Framework data model. It also
>   adds great flexibility and
>   functionality to the DetailsView,
>   FormView, GridView, and ListView
>   controls in the form of smart
>   validation and the ability to easily
>   change the display of these controls
>   using templates.

Answer (score 3):

It's an addon that integrates into existing ASP.NET controls such as GridView. It looks at the model exposed by LINQ2SQL or EF to provide a richer editing interface. Use it for simple CRUD apps.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET DDS is the drag and drop change here and there and you have a data Driven web application ready to go kind'a thing.

[Matt Berseth](http://mattberseth.com/) has a [few good posts about this](http://mattberseth.com/blog/dynamic_data/)

Answer (score 1):

This is a great tool for cranking out a simple app very quickly. Useful for prototyping or very simple websites, or temporary "bridge" sites to get users up and running while the real app is written.

This is not for building robust, scalable enterprise app's with complex UI's, a lot of business logic, or non-CRUD features.

It's one tool for your tool belt, not a universal tool.